# Unity C#, Using LINQ on multiple target platforms

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any way in Unity of defining resources for a particular platform that should be ignored by Unity when on another build platform?

I like to use LINQ, but when my target is the Web Player I get the error message:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Linq' does not exist in the namespace `System.Xml'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I can solve this by copying the System.Xml.Linq.dll to my Plugins folder, and now Unity knows about LINQ.

Then when I switch target to Android I get the error message:

```
error CS0433: The imported type `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' is defined multiple times
```

Which is resolved by deleting System.Xml.Linq.dll from the Plugins folder.

I'd like Unity to ignore System.Xml.Linq.dll when on Android and notice it when on Web Player target.

A solution for getting Unity to see LINQ when on Web Player platform without copying the DLL into the project, would also be fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

there is this in the unity docs:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Comment: Sorry but could you be more specific? All I see in your link is conditional code for specific platforms, I don't see any mention of files/resources? My problem is a DLL file that mess up the compilation on different platforms.

Comment: ah... it doesn't cover DLLs "yet", coming in unity 5: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/exclude-dll-on-specific-platform.113706/#post-1812988 (some options in that code too)